# dc.js add filter on multiple values

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I am using dc.js,

I want to add filter based on checkbox selection. Here is my scenario

[image]

When i select checkboxes based on that i need filter.

Here is my code

```
     var ndx = crossfilter(readData);

    var practiceDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
            return d.practice_name;
        }); 

    $('#treeview input[name="practice_name[]"]:checked').each(function() {
            if(searchPracticeArray.indexOf($(this).val()) == -1)
                searchPracticeArray.push($(this).val());
                // If  I added searchPracticeArray as filter parameter then it's not working 
                // searchPracticeArray value are ['LPS','Mercy']

practiceDimension = practiceDimension.filter($(this).val());
                bubbleChart.filter($(this).val());       

        });
```

Currently i have two checkbox but it should be more then two and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter a dimension based on a function. I'd recommend doing this in your case. [API documentation](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-dimension_filterFunction).

However, keep in mind that this function will be run over every record in your data set at some point, so you'll want to just do the DOM query once and then save those values to an array within the scope of the function, then filter on that.

Comment: Hi, I have found some logic, Please check that and let me know is this right way to do filter on multiples fields.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have find some solutions like this

Here searchPracticeArray is array value which stored value based on selection.

```
if(searchPracticeArray.length > 0)
{
var practiceDimensionFilterData;
for(var d=0; d < searchPracticeArray.length; d++ )
{
    pract_name_search = searchPracticeArray[d].key;            
    practiceDimensionFilterData = readData.filter(function(d){ return(d.practice_name == pract_name_search)})            
    practiceDimension2[d] = practiceDimensionFilterData
    if(d > 0)
    {
    practiceDimension6 = practiceDimension2[0].concat(practiceDimension2[d])
    }
    else{
    practiceDimension6 = practiceDimension2[d];
    }
    bubbleChart.filter(pract_name_search);
}
ndx = crossfilter(practiceDimension6);  

}
```

Comment: No, this is not correct, or rather, it doesn't use Crossfilter. You need to use Crossfilter's dimension and filter APIs.